# "Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file" crashes all Windows 10 apps immediately

Tags: windows-10, audio, filesystems, file-permissions, security-policy

I've been having this problem for a day or two now.
Every time I try to open any Windows 10 App or App Service (Groovy, Realtek Audio Manager, Photo Viewer, wsreset.exe), I'm greeted with `"Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file.  You may not have the appropriate permissions to open this file."`, and the program immediately exits.

This has made it impossible for me to open many common files or change my Realtek audio settings, which is problematic because I use my computer for audio production.

**What I have tried:**

```
    - Fresh in-place reinstall of Windows 10 (keeping personal files)
    - Fresh in-place reinstall of Windows 10 (wiping everything)
    - Giving full ownership of the entire `C:\` drive tree to `everyone`
    - Moving the files I want to access onto my `D:\` drive
    - Running programs as administrator
    - (attempting to) Make the entire tree of `C:\` not read-only
    - Prayer
```

Any help would be much appreciated; I need my computer for work and something makes me fear the problem will only worsen.

**Edit:**  I have logged in to my computer's built in Administrator account, and it still gives me an error when I try to open a Windows Store app, but instead just says something along the lines of "the app failed to start".

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have major problems with Windows.

I can suggest these steps:

- Check the SMART data of the disk for problems (for example using
  [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy))
- Check the Event Viewer for errors
- Run `chkdsk` to check for file allocation corruption
- Run
  [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html)
  and DISM (described at the end of this link)
- If all else fails
  [Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Well, I can't do the Event Viewer now, as I did a complete reinstall of Windows, making sure to wipe everything, and I'm still having the same problem.

I'll try these and get back to you on that

Comment: So, I've already done an in-place Refresh -and- Reset.  I've run chkdsk and sfc /scannow, and both say there are no problems.  I ran all the DISM stuff I could.  Either there was nothing of note in the error log, or can't quite understand what the logs mean.  And, I'm not entirely sure how to check SMART data with Speccy; I couldn't find much information online.

Comment: With Speccy, go into the Storage section. The SMART values you will see are not always obvious, but Speccy will mark them for you as good or bad.

Comment: Ah, gotchya.  Just took a look.  It says all is good

Comment: This sounds incredible. Is there anything special about your computer or hard disk? Maybe dual boot with Linux?  You could also run [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/)  for as many passes as possible, as a general hardware test.

Comment: Well, I did just assemble it about two weeks ago.  My fear now is I somehow missassembled it in some rare, specifically-problematic way.

Comment: MemTest86 is a good start, as it tests RAM and incidentally also the CPU & memory controller.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, but heck, I'll give it a try